# How do I create an OR filter in Taleo Connect Client?

Tags: xml, taleo, taleo-connect-client

I want to create an Export in Taleo Connect Client to find candidates that are missing either an Address, City, or ZipCode. However, I don't know how to create a filter with multiple conditions.

For example: The filters below will find candidates where `Address`, `City`, and `ZipCode` are empty.

```
<quer:filtering>
  <quer:isNull>
    <quer:field path="Address"/>
  </quer:isNull>
</quer:filtering>
<quer:filtering>
  <quer:isNull>
    <quer:field path="City"/>
  </quer:isNull>
</quer:filtering>
<quer:filtering>
  <quer:isNull>
    <quer:field path="ZipCode"/>
  </quer:isNull>
</quer:filtering>
```

How would I filter candidates where `Address`, `City`, **OR** `ZipCode` are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest multiple `<quer:or>` statements to combine pairs of two conditions.

```
<quer:filtering xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:or>
    <!--Condition 1-->
    <quer:or>
      <!--Condition 2-->
      <quer:or>
        <!--Condition 3-->
        <!--Condition 4-->
      </quer:or>
    </quer:or>
  </quer:or>
</quer:filtering>
```

---

**Complex filter if Address, City, or ZipCode are null:**

```
<quer:filtering xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:or>
    <quer:isNull>
      <quer:field path="Address"/>
    </quer:isNull>
    <quer:or>
      <quer:isNull>
        <quer:field path="City"/>
      </quer:isNull>
      <quer:isNull>
        <quer:field path="ZipCode"/>
      </quer:isNull>
    </quer:or>
  </quer:or>
</quer:filtering>
```

Full Export:

```
<quer:query productCode="RC1704" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Candidate" locale="en" mode="CSV" largegraph="true" preventDuplicates="false" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:subQueries/>
  <quer:projections>
    <quer:projection alias="CandidateNumber">
      <quer:field path="Number"/>
    </quer:projection>
  </quer:projections>
  <quer:projectionFilterings/>
  <quer:filterings>
    <quer:filtering xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
      <!--If Address, City, or ZipCode are null-->
      <quer:or>
        <quer:isNull>
          <quer:field path="Address"/>
        </quer:isNull>
        <quer:or>
          <quer:isNull>
            <quer:field path="City"/>
          </quer:isNull>
          <quer:isNull>
            <quer:field path="ZipCode"/>
          </quer:isNull>
        </quer:or>
      </quer:or>
    </quer:filtering>
  </quer:filterings>
  <quer:sortings/>
  <quer:sortingFilterings/>
  <quer:groupings/>
  <quer:joinings/>
</quer:query>
```

Thanks to [ThinkTalent Tech Blog](http://www.thinktalent.net/Communities/Blogs/entryid/6/thinktalent-tech-blog-how-to-specify-a-logical-or-filter-in-tcc) for demonstrating how to use `<quer:or>`.